# Calculating CRC of file as numeric value using Crypto++

Tags: c++, c++11, cryptography, crypto++

I am receiving file along with its CRC which is numeric value. I must recalculate CRC on received file and compare it. I am using Crypto++ but it didn't give me numeric value. Please let me know how to calculate CRC32 of file using Crypto++.

```cxx
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/crc.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
typedef int UInt32;
#include <cryptopp/files.h>

using namespace std;

string calculateCRC(const string& fileName)
{
   string result;
   CryptoPP::CRC32 hash;
   CryptoPP::FileSource(fileName.c_str(),true,
    new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash,
    new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));
   return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << endl << calculateCRC("./test.cpp");
}
```

This gives result as "\271\063\307Q".
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This gives result as "\271\063\307Q"

I believe this is an octal display of 3 bytes of binary data. Under GDB, you can use `x/4b <address>` to print it in ASCII: `B9 33 C7 ...`.

Add a [`HexEncoder`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder) to the [filter chain](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) if you want it in ASCII instead of binary:

```cxx
CRC32 hash;
string result;

FileSource fs(fileName.c_str(), true,
    new HashFilter(hash,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(result))));

cout << result << endl;
```

Its output will be similar to:

```
$ ./test.exe 
80BA6847
```

---

> ```
> typedef int UInt32;
> ```

This may not be correct. `int` suffers overflow and undefined behavior; while `unsigned int` does not.